# Wireshark/PCAP XML attributes explained

Tags: wireshark, xml, pcap

I'm generating XML-formatted output from a Wireshark dump using the following command:

```
tshark -r my_wireshark_data.pcap -T pdml > my_wireshark_data.xml
```

Looking at the XML file generated, I cannot figure out the meaning of the **pos** and **size** attributes, which appear everywhere.  Can anyone explain, or provide a link to documentation?

Output snippet:

```
<pdml version="0" creator="wireshark/1.10.14" time="Mon Jun 20 15:27:45 2016" capture_file="my_wireshark_data.pcap">
<packet>
  <proto name="ip" ...>
    <field name="ip.version" showname="Version: 4" size="1" pos="14" show="4" value="45"/>
  </proto>
</pdml>
```

Also:

Why is **value** set to `45` instead of `4`?

What is the difference between **showname** and **show**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Can anyone explain, or provide a link to documentation?

> Why is value set to 45 instead of 4.

- `value` (45) is the actual packet data, in hex, that this field covers
- `show` (4) is the representation of the packet data (`value`) **as it would  appear in a display filter.**

> What is the difference between showname and show?

- `showname` is the label used to describe this field in the protocol   tree.

  This is usually the descriptive name of the protocol, followed by some representation of the `value`.
- `show` (4) is the representation of the packet data (`value`) **as it would  appear in a display filter.** (in this case the version number)

> The "`<field>`" tag
>
> "`<field>`" tags can have the following attributes:
>
> - `name` - the display filter name for the field
> - `showname` - the label used to describe this field in the protocol      tree. This is usually the descriptive name of the protocol,
>       followed by some representation of the value.
> - `pos` - the starting offset within the packet data where this       field starts
> - `size` - the number of octets in the packet data that this field        covers.
> - `value` - the actual packet data, in hex, that this field covers
> - `show` - the representation of the packet data ('value') as it would        appear in a display filter.
>
> Some dissectors sometimes place text into the protocol tree, without
>   using a field with a field-name. Those appear in PDML as "`<field>`"
>   tags with no 'name' attribute, but with a 'show' attribute giving that
>   text.

Source [Protocol Dissection in XML Format](https://github.com/boundary/wireshark/blob/master/doc/README.xml-output)

Comment: you explained it perfectly, thank you.  Cheers for the link.

Comment: If **value** `(45)`, which I understand is the actual packet data, is in hex, how does that relate to **show** value, in this case `4`?  45 hex is 69 decimal, so I am missing something.

Comment: As far as I can tell the `value` has also been called `unmasked value` in some other places. My guess is that the display filter extracts from or manipulates the `value` to turn it into `show`. I don't know the details of how or why this happens (I'm no Wireshark expert).